# Laravel MPDF Temporary files directory "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\laravel/../temp/" is not writable

Tags: pdf, laravel-8, mpdf

i have the same problem, i've tried to change permission on the Security section of the **main** and **sub folders**.
i changed `temp_dir =>` to many locations as `storage_path('/temp')` // `public_path('temp')` // `base_path('temp')`

but notthing new , always getting same error.

`Temporary files directory "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\laravel\../temp//mpdf" is not writable`

i deployed my project laravel on windows server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

i added `tempdir` path as parameter in loadview function

`$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf', $data, [], ['tempDir' => storage_path('tempdir') ])->save($pdfFilePath);`

`$pdf->stream('nicesnippets.pdf');`